# Combining multiple GET endpoints into a single resource

Tags: python, flask-restful

I'm using flask restful to create an API and I want to refactor my code. I have something as shown below:

```
class Makequestions(Resource):
    def get(self):
    #somecode

class Managequestions(Resource):
    def get(self, user_id):
    #somecode

API.add_resource(MakeQuestions, '/MakeQuestions')
API.add_resource(ManageQuestions, '/ManageQuestions/<int:user_id>')
```

I need to combine these two into a single resource with multiple endpoints say forexample:

```
class Makequestions(Resource):
    def get(self):
    #somecode

    def get(self, user_id):
    #somecode
```

maybe with a final url along the lines of

```
API.add_resource(MakeQuestions, '/MakeQuestions','/MakeQuestions/<int:user_id>')
```

I'm hoping this will reduce the amount of times I have to create a 'Resource class' Is there someway I can do this?

Comment: Whole point of flask restfull is to separate resource from collections. I would suggest you to stay with creating one class for single resource (GET [one], PUT [update one], DELETE [remove one]) and other class for collection resource (GET [plural], POST [create new])

Comment: I like how it's done in #django_rest_framework - a resource class has list() for getting the collection and retrieve() for getting just a single resource. I think it makes more sense, though flask-restful uses different approach as it seems

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with the Flask RESTful API, but while Python will let you overload a class with `get(self)` and `get(self, question_id)`, if you're "making" a REST resource, that shouldn't be a GET request.

REST API URLs should not contain verbs such as "MakeObject" or "ManageObject". The HTTP method should dictate the operation being performed.

That being said, `POST /question` would make a question object. `GET /question/:id` should return a specific one.

Therefore, you'd define a `post(self)` and `get(self, question_id)`  under a single `Question` Resource. Or add a `Questions` resource as well where you can get all questions, and move the post method there.

If you replace "Question" with "TODO", your problem is not that different from the [full example on the Flask RESTful site](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example)

Note: plural URLs are also preferred over singular, so in your case, `/questions` and `/questions/:id` should be defined as two resources

Answer (score 0):

The naming of your functions aside, you could probably do something like

```
class Question(Resource):
    def get(self, user_id=0):
        if(user_id):
            return specific question
        return list of questions
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable idea to me... any thoughts from anyone else?